# Managing an Activity with many states

Tags: android

I have an activity that has possibly many different states.

**For example**

- no internet
- no license
- logged in
- not logged in
- pending
- error
- restricted
- deprecated

At the moment I have `if statements` that determine the appropriate state of the application and enable or disable views as required.  I was thinking that some sore of STATE pattern might be better.

Can someone give me some idea of how I might do this with an Activity like this?  Or in this case is an if statement like this a better option as the views are tightly coupled to the Activity anyway.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't disable the views for some of thise things ie no internet. Just let the user try to interact and give relevant error messages.

A good rule of thumb is that if you're changing the views significantly from one state to the other, maybe it should be a different activity? There should be very little reason to change the LAYOUT of views based on state.

Comment: The user cannot continue if there is not internet, so I don't allow this.  The activity displays three different steps, once on step is complete the next one becomes available.  If I had a layout for every step it would be too confusing for the user.

Comment: Having an app that ONLY works with internet seems odd to me. I guess apps like pandora require internet, maybe you should check how they handle that situation? As for your second part, it's your job to not make it confusing for the user. You can have different activities that all expand a slightly different layout. If by enabled you mean you're not changing the layout and are really just enabling things like buttons to be clickable, then that's probably fine as an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This question is as old as the internet now, but the OP should really check out [Stateless4J](http://code.google.com/p/stateless4j/).

It provides lightweight Finite State Machines with easy syntax. I use it in all my Java projects.